# How to work with multiple rss files in j2me(java)

Tags: java-me, rss

i am developing Rss Feed Reader App in j2me(java) for 2 xml files,but my for loop is

having a problem,xml file is giving null,when i run my application ,control is not going to this method in my loop getXMLFeed(url1); ,instead of that it is completing for loop.can any one help?is my looping is correct?once check my source Code?i am having problem with for loop

check my source code:

```
 urls = new String[2];//Array Declaration
 urls[0] = "http://www.teluguone.com/news/tonefeeds/topnews/topnews-20.rss";
 urls[1] = "http://www.teluguone.com/news/tonefeeds/topstory/topstory-25.rss";
 for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) //iterration
 {        
      myThread = new ParseThread(this);           
      myThread.getXMLFeed(url1);                     
      myDysplay.setCurrent(mform);
 }

public void getXMLFeed(final String url) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                    myConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);//HttpConnection
                    InputStream stream = myConnection.openInputStream();
                    ParseXMLFeed(stream);
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just forgot to paste the line, but it seems that you are no calling `t.start()` inside `getXMLFeed` method.

Comment: yaa,i am using t.start() in my application,but i have not pasted it in sample code

Comment: when i run my application,initially,the loop is executed completely and the form is displayed on device,with no initial  data,and it is promting "Allow application to use for network for sending and receiving data? with yes or no buttons,when i press yes,the result of two rss feed xml files titles are mixed and displayed on device.my requirement is to read initially first rss file after that to read second rss file,in a loop
myThread = new ParseThread(this); // or initialize this object somewhere in the startApp method,i think,with in the loop ,i am not able to open the stream?

Comment: Move myDysplay.setCurrent(mform) to before the for and do not create a Thread in getXMLFeed. This will result in a sequential execution.